# C++ How to have a class relying on a namespace and that namespace relying on the class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, namespaces, forward-declaration

So I have a class with some member variables that are instances of a structure defined within a namespace, and a function within that same namespace has a parameter that is a pointer to an instance of the above mentioned class.

This looks like:

SomeClass.h

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

include "SomeNamespace.h"

class SomeClass
{
private:
    SomeNamespace::SomeStructure instance1, instance2;

    ...
```

SomeNamespace.h

```
#ifndef SOME_NAMESPACE_H
#define SOME_NAMESPACE_H

#include "SomeClass.h"

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    namespace AnotherNamespace
    {
        void SomeFunction( SomeClass *pSomeClass );
    }

    struct SomeStructure
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

The errors I was receiving:

```
Error C2065 'SomeClass': undeclared identifier  
Error C2653 'SomeNamespace' : is not a class or namespace name
```

The first error related to:

```
void SomeFunction( SomeClass *pSomeClass );
```

The second error relates to:

```
SomeNamespace::SomeStructure instance1, instance2;
```

I fixed the first error by adding a forward declaration 'class SomeClass;' to the top of the file:

SomeNamespace.h

```
#ifndef SOME_NAMESPACE_H
#define SOME_NAMESPACE_H

#include "SomeClass.h"

class SomeClass;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    namespace AnotherNamespace
    {
        void SomeFunction( SomeClass *pSomeClass );
    }

    struct SomeStructure
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

I attempted to fix error two doing the same thing for the namespace and structure:

SomeClass.h

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

include "SomeNamespace.h"

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    struct SomeStructure;
}

class SomeClass
{
private:
    SomeNamespace::SomeStructure instance1, instance2;

    ...
```

Doing the forward declaration on the namespace and the structure within gives me these errors:

```
'SomeClass::instance1' uses undefined struct 'SomeNamespace::SomeStructure'
'SomeClass::instance2' uses undefined struct 'SomeNamespace::SomeStructure'
```

I have already searched for this issue posted by another user, but I have been unsuccessful locating a post.

If anyone has an issue with this question and feel they need to rate it badly, then please also add a comment as to why it is a bad question to help me avoid the same mistake next time.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: A classic.  Please search SO for recursive include or header file organization.

Comment: Note that your forward declaration of `SomeStructure` is only inside namespace `SomeNamespace`, and not inside `SomeNamespace::AnotherNamespace` which is how `SomeClass` is trying to use it.

Comment: Josh that was a typing mistake here, and not how the actual code was. Thank you for pointing that out, I have edited the main post to reflect this.

Comment: Also, note you cannot ask the compiler to define a variable, e.g. `instance1` from an incomplete declaration of `SomeStructure`.  It needs to layout memory for `SomeClass`.

Comment: Do you know a solution David? That is the issue here, but I just do not know how to solve it

Comment: @MikeO You can use forward declarations for *pointers* to undefined types, but not for the undefined types themselves.  The normal approach here would be to declare `SomeNamespace::SomeStructure* instance1, instance2;`.  Of course that means that `instance1` and `instance2` would have to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: You can't have a circular include. You need break that using forward declarations.

Comment: You can't #include SomeClass in SomeNamespace.h. You're going to have to reassess your design.

Comment: @drescherjm But he is using `#include` guards, so that isn't a problem here.

Comment: Include guards do not (on their own) solve the circular include problem.

Comment: I also have the forward declarations already drescherjm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've shown us, you only need a forward declaration of SomeClass in SomeNamespace.h, not a full include:

```
#ifndef SOME_NAMESPACE_H
#define SOME_NAMESPACE_H

// #include "SomeClass.h"  // << don't do this.

class SomeClass;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    namespace AnotherNamespace
    {
        void SomeFunction( SomeClass *pSomeClass );
    }
```

The above is valid because a pointer-to SomeClass doesn't need to know anything about SomeClass other than it's a class.

Comment: Note that the recursive include is deleted.

Comment: I have tried this and within the SomeFunction definition where I make a call to a member function of SomeClass I get an error stating: 'left of <function name> must point to class/struct/union/generic type'

Comment: Which I fixed by adding #include "Company.h" to the .cpp file. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really do need circular references between `SomeStructure` and `SomeClass`, you can use pointers since the underlying type doesn't have to be fully defined in advance.

SomeNamespace.h:

```
#ifndef SOME_NAMESPACE_H
#define SOME_NAMESPACE_H

#include "SomeClass.h"

namespace SomeNamespace {
    namespace AnotherNamespace {
        void SomeFunction(SomeClass *pSomeClass);
    }
    struct SomeStructure {
    };
}

#endif
```

SomeClass.h:

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

namespace SomeNamespace {
    struct SomeStructure;
}

class SomeClass {
private:
    SomeNamespace::SomeStructure *pInstance1, *pInstance2;
public:
    SomeClass(SomeNamespace::SomeStructure *pInstance1, SomeNamespace::SomeStructure *pInstance2) 
        : pInstance1(pIntance1), pInstance2(pInstance2) {}
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "SomeNamespace.h"
#include "SomeClass.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SomeNamespace::SomeStructure *pInstance1 = new SomeNamespace::SomeStructure();
    SomeNamespace::SomeStructure *pInstance2 = new SomeNamespace::SomeStructure();
    SomeClass someClass(pInstance1, pInstance2);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, main.cpp can create your `SomeStructure` objects, since it sees the fully defined class, and it can also instantiate `SomeClass` for the same reason.

Comment: Note also that the creation of `pInstance1` and `pInstance2` could also happen inside `SomeClass.cpp` after both `SomeStructure` and `SomeClass` are fully defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider code that contains:

```
#include "SomeClass.h"
```

When SomeClass.h is processed, the #define guard is created.  Then SomeNamespace.h is opened and processed.  Its guard is created.  Then SomeClass.h is reprocessed - only the guard exists and prevents any definitions.  This is why the compiler is generating undefined errors.